# PHP Array Function inside Class Confusion

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working with some existing code, specifically the JQuery File Upload Plugin. There is one large class and within that there are some functions i'm  trying to customize.  Problem is there are a few lines of code that make no sense to me.

```
protected function get_file_object($file_name) {
    //whole bunch of code is here that generates an object file file size
    //and other information related to the image that was in the array.
    //removed the code to be concise, just know it returns an object.
        return $file;
}


protected function get_file_objects() {
        return array_values(
        array_filter(
        array_map(
            array($this, 'get_file_object'),
            scandir($this->options['upload_dir'])
        )));
}
```

Okay, so what I don't understand is what is going on inside array_map.  I know array map takes a callback and then an array as a arguments.  scandir grabs an array from a directory.

Its the callback that makes no sense to me.   I looked at the syntax for the array() function on the php documentation and it didn't say anything about taking two arguments like this.  obviously the second one is a function, that's in quotes?  I understand what the code is doing just not how its doing it.

Is this some undocumented functionality?

Comment: That's an object method callback reference.  Instead of just the function, you have to pass the object reference `$this` and the function name, as a tuple (2-part array).  The fact this is inside a class should be disclosed in the question, though it's obvious from the use of `$this` and the `protected` modifiers on the functions (methods).

Comment: Sorry spaced on the class.  Will add that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `array_map` is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) one of the things that is a callable is an array where the first element represents the instance (or classname if the method is static) and the second the methodname. So `array($this, 'get_file_object')` is refering to the `get_file_object` of the current instance (`$this` is the current instance).

Comment: Basically, `array($this, 'get_file_object')` is "callback" syntax for `$this->get_file_object` :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, that's a little bit easier :)